# Flash camera access without security question

Tags: webcam, flash

Is it possible to access a machines web camera with Flash without needing the users permission?

The project I plan on using Flash in will not be web based and run in a standard flash projector or in a swfStudio projector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It is not. This is similar to the question "Is it possible to save files on a user's hard disk using JavaScript". It just might be possible, but then it's a hack. It won't work forever [if you ever find a way to do so] because it's simply not supported. And it's not supported for a reason: security. It isn't something like an inavailability of technology, so there is no reason it will ever be available in the future.

P.S: For JavaScript, HTML5 does have the option of saving files on the user's hard disk, but again, not without permissions [i'm not taking into account cookies here]

Comment: I imagined that to be the case alright. Is there any chance that something like SwfStudio would be able to provide a solution I wonder?

Comment: I don't think so. Again, FP security (avoid apps recording the user without him/her to confirm). For same reason Flash apps that want to use the cam or the mic must be *at least* the size of that dialog or they will silently fail.

Comment: Bottom line: there is no solution. There isn't one supposed to be. The specifications for such technologies assert that user intervention is a MUST before certain such access is provided to the application. Hence, what you are looking for isn't a "solution", it's a "workaround" [or actually, a "hack"]. And no, for the white side of the world atleast, none such exists [or none should.. in an ideal world atleast] :D

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use AIR?
In AIR you can access the camera and no message will be displayed.

Comment: Sure. Try this http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/marketplace/index.cfm?event=marketplace.offering&marketplaceid=1&offeringid=10080

Comment: Thanks Andy, Air looks like a possible option for my specific case. But I need to call C code from it, so I'll see if SwfStudio and Air play well together. But that's my problem, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the machine you are deploying to, you can use the [Flash Settings Manager](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager.html) to always allow camera access.